# AutoFit_LastRow , randomly works , with no error raised

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below , to processing rows on the destination sheet.
All macro works fine , but sometimes the line code of `AutoFit_LastRow` not works (that part code has no effect) with no error raised. 
**The expected result is** ,Last row to be autofit and after autofitted if Row Height < 45 then Row Height = 45
In Advance, thanks for all assistance.

```
Sub AutoFit_LastRow()
 
    Dim sh As Worksheets: Set sh = Sheets(8)
    Dim srng As Range: Set srng = Sheets(4).Range("B3:B500")
    Dim cell As Range
     For Each cell In srng
       If cell.value = "Completed" Then
             cell.Offset(, 6).Resize(1, 3).value = Array("Close", Now, Application.UserName)
             sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 32).value = cell.EntireRow.value
             sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).value = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 2
 
             sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit '----Sometimes has no effect
 
          If sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Rows.RowHeight < 45 Then
             sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Rows.RowHeight = 45
            End If
      End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)` returns the last cell in A:A column, so its `Rows` property will always return only 1 row. So, `sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.AutoFit` should be enough. But your way should not be a cause for erroring. Your code should work as it looks. It will do nothing only if the row in discussion has already the autofitting height. Maybe a not visible character (a space, for instance) of a larger font can produce this sensation. I am afraid that your code cannot be checked, not being able to build a reproductible example. Is the case on the same row?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,these rows (on destination) is pre manually formatted {Color ,Font,..} and no values at all inside it , and the macro using absolute values.
Actually I found that copy by direct assignment is very fast and code modifications is very easy (I am not expert on arrays).
I post that question ,as `Autofit` is randomly works. Anyhow, thanks for trying to help me.